# How to handle errors (AbstractRestfulController)?

Tags: zend-framework2

I try to use AbstractRestfulController. I create controller class:

```
class MyController extends AbstractRestfulController{

    public function getList(){
        $data = array();

        return new JsonModel(array(
            'data' => $data,
        ));
    }

    public function get($id){
        $data = array();

        return new JsonModel(array(
            'data' => $data,
        ));
    }

    public function create($data){
        $data = array();

        return new JsonModel(array(
            'data' => $data,
        ));
    }

    public function update($id, $data){
        $data = array();

        return new JsonModel(array(
            'data' => $data,
        ));
    }

    public function delete($id){
        $data = array();

        return new JsonModel(array(
            'data' => $data,
        ));
    }

}
```

and routing:

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'mylink' => array(
                'type'    => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/mylink[/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'MyModule\Controller\My',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'MyModule\Controller\My' => 'MyModule\Controller\MyController',
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ),
    ),
);
```

but what happens when the user calls the wrong method or wrong id or anything else? I would like to handle it myself. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your api should still return a response in the requested format (json, xml, etc), usually with some error code/message describing the issue, and an appropriate http response code. It's up to you to tell consumers of your api what the expected responses will be, but it's up to them to handle it when they get it wrong.

From that standpoint it's a simple case of setting a response and populating your model with relevant information to return, a typical response might look like the following...

```
public function get($id)
{
    // some processing to find id ...

    // no id found
    if (!$found) {
        // set 404 Not Found response
        $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404);
        // return message to client
        return new JsonModel(array(
            'error' => 404,
            'reason' => sprint_f('Requested id "%s" not found', $id'),
        ));
    }
}
```

Obviously do the same for your other methods, and try to use an appropriate [HTTP response code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: But what if there is bad url? If I set 'error/404' in 'template_map', it return me standard text/html page from view/error. I can not assign the controller/module/whatever to handle errors?

Comment: That's not what you asked. For a bad url there's more to consider, like does your site also serve standard http pages? If not, you could fashion a 404 view strategy that returns a JsonModel in the event of a 404 response from a route. If it does also handle http, you'd have to come up with a strategy that can figure out if it's a bad api request OR a real user who mistyped a link. I think you need to consider what's acceptable, like I said, it's not your responsibility to handle your clients errors for them. That they received a 404 along with a html instead of json response should be enough.